# How to run powershell commands in background from a button in web page. Is that possible?

Tags: html, powershell

I want to run this command "(Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Computersystem).Domain" in PowerShell to know the Domain name and want to know whether they joined correct domain or not.

But it should be automatic. I want to do it from a web page with the help of a button , when they click that button the PowerShell command should run in the background and the code should check whether the user has joined correct domain or not. If they join correct one, my web page will display "Success" else, it should show up "failure".

How can I do this?

Comment: What will you be using as a backend for the website? ASP.NET?

Comment: I am building the UI page on service now, so jelly script and Java script.

Comment: So, you want the PowerShell commands executed on the client computer? That's not possible.

Comment: Yes, I want commands to be executed on client computer when the button is clicked, why it is not possible? Any reason? Are there any security constraints?

Comment: Yeah, the browser is effectively a sandbox - the opposite would be terrifying, if websites could execute arbitrary code in the user context on the client system. Best you can do is offer a script or executable for download that the users can run themselves

Comment: Oh got it, thanks! I will think of an alternative.

Comment: Do you not have access to the systems?